# Corrupted Dolphin settings

Tags: dolphin

I'm running Kubuntu 22.04. My Dolphin settings  seem to be corrupted, since when I try to change them I get into a loop, as indicated by a whirling circle.  How do I get past this?

Comment: What do you mean by "getting into a loop"? Do they not being applied when you close the settings?

Comment: The  loop is indicated by the usual whirling circle, which makes it impossible to do anything else.

Comment: I see. Try running a `HOME=/tmp dolphin` and see if that changes anything. That would temporarily make dolphin use `/tmp` as its configuration directory, so you can check your assumption that settings got somehow corrupted by testing if it works when used with another config dir. If that's the case you can check what settings and where it creates and try removing/replacing them in your actual HOME.